# Program crashes while creating list in C

Tags: c

I am creating a simple single link list. In function `listIn()`, until `malloc()` everything works just fine, but just after `malloc()` is executed my program crashes. I am not able to understand why?
It gives output like:

---

Process exited after 3.055 seconds with return value 3221225477
Press any key to continue . . .

Code:

#### `main.c`

```
//main 
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include"structure.h"
#include"List.h"

int main ()
{
    listIn(1);
    displ();
}
//end of main function.
```

#### `List.h`

```
//custom header file List.h (begin)

List *lstart = NULL;
void listIn(int hcode);
size_t listIsEmpty();
void dispList();

//function definition queueIn() to insert element into queue.

void listIn(int hcode)
{
    tmplist = (List *) malloc (sizeof ( List ) );
    if (tmplist = NULL)
    {
        puts("Memory Not available");
        return;
    }
    tmplist->lcode = hcode;
    tmplist->llink = lstart;
    lstart = tmplist;   
}

//end of function queueIn()

//function declaration displ() used to print queue

void displ()
{
    if( listIsEmpty() )
    {
        puts("List is Empty");
    }
    else
    {
        List *ptr;
        ptr = lstart;
        while(ptr != NULL)
        {
            printf("%d\n", ptr->lcode);
            ptr = ptr->llink; 
        }
    }
}

// function displ() end


// function declaration listIsEmpty() to check the status of queue.

size_t listIsEmpty()
{
    if(lstart == NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

// custom header file List.h(end)
```

#### `structure.h`

```
//custom header file structure.h(begin)
// definition of all the structures
#include<stdbool.h>//for boolean data type.
#ifndef STRUCTURE_H_
#define STRUCTURE_H_
#include<stdbool.h>

typedef struct lnode
{
    int lcode;
    struct lnode *llink; 
}List;
List *tmplist;
#endif

// custom header file structure.h(end)
```

Comment: first problem: `if (tmplist = NULL)` --> `if (tmplist == NULL)`

Comment: Please re-compile your code with warnings enabled and fix those.  Next, please show us what is within your List.h file - we don't know what a "List" is.  Warnings enabled catches the above mentioned '=' vs '==' issue

Comment: @MichaelDorgan it is at the bottom of the listing.

Comment: Are varibles `lStart` and `lstart` identical? Where second one is declared?

Comment: @oklas yes they are equal. Thanks for pointing it out i have corrected my code.

Comment: it is useful to put the constant first in your equality comparisons so that the compiler reports an error when you try to do this: `if (NULL = tmplist)`

Comment: @yano Thanks a lot that was the only problem. I spent hours on this and couldn't realise the bug. Thanks now my code is running properly.

Comment: @bruceg Thank you for the tip. I will keep this in mind for future.

Comment: cool! As @MichaelDorgan suggested, compile with warnings enabled (at least `-Wall` for `gcc`),, that would've saved you a lot of time in this case.

Comment: @yano sure. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: You should not normally include function declarations in a header file.  If the functions are not `static`, then only one file in a program can ever include the header, which defeats the purpose of having a header.  You can put `static inline` functions in a header if you're confident they will be inlined, but you wouldn't be asking this question if you knew about that.  You should have a separate implementation file (maybe `List.c`) that defines the functions that are declared in the header.  _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ The implementation file will include the header; the main program file (and any other consumer files) will also include the header.  This gives you cross-checking that the code is all self-consistent.  I'm not convinced that `structure.h` gives you anything useful.  It's content should probably be in `List.h`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here

```
if (tmplist = NULL)
```

This sets tmplist to NULL immediately after allocation. This fails the `if` test so the block isn't entered. The next line after the `if` crashes immediately.

Should read

```
if (tmplist == NULL)
```

You should be getting warnings about this. Always compile with warnings turned on.